# Word for beginning a statement with a disclaimer / caveat / hedge when you are worried you might say something incorrect

Tags: single-word-requests

For some reason I am convinced that such a word exists, that I've heard it used in classroom settings, and that I'll recognize it when I see it. But I have no idea what it is. I tried googling this elusive word and failed miserably; I asked a few friends, but they couldn't think of it either. Help!

Suppose someone says: "Well, I don't know much about this topic, and I could be wrong, but XYZ."  I feel there's a word to describe the opening that leads into XYZ. It's a sort of hedging: you aren't fully committing yourself; you're worried about being wrong. I can almost hear a high-school teacher saying "Don't start an answer with a *_*."

Any ideas?

Comment: The word "*disclaimer*" from your title seems most apt to me. For obscure vocabulary words which mean "starting a statement with a hypocritical and disingenuous denial", try "*aphophasis*" on for size.

Comment: In linguistic terms, *a [hedge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hedge_(linguistics)) is a mitigating word or sound used to lessen the impact of an utterance*. Arguably that's a somewhat technical usage that wouldn't necessarily be either used or understood by most people, but practically everyone would be familiar with *"Stop hedging!"* used to mean *"Stop beating around the bush! Give me a straight answer!"*.

Comment: disclaimer, caveat and hedge are already words for disclaimers, caveats, and hedges.  There's no need for another.

Comment: Actually, I think @Oldcat's right, but maybe you just need the right phrase to use those words. I'd say "Don't *preface* everything with a disclaimer" or "You don't need to *couch* every response with a caveat"

Comment: Also, don't apologize in advance. (While you're at it, don't thank in advance, either, but that's another topic.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may seem oxymoronic to identify the prefatory statement, "Well, I don't know much about this topic" as a *qualification*, but the speaker is qualifying (that is, limiting) the level of confidence with which the statement is offered and with which it should be received, by asserting up-front his or her lack of qualifications (in the sense of credentialed competence or expertise) to make the statement.

In addition to *qualification*, words that might be used to describe prefacing a statement with a preamble that narrows the applicability or reach of the statement by downplaying the speaker's independent knowledge or expertise are *proviso*, *stipulation*, *reservation*, and (two words) *limiting condition*, along with *caveat*, *disclaimer*, and *hedge* (which the poster identified at the outset).

Answer (score 1):

Some of the following will fit reasonably well into the example sentence, “Don’t start an answer with [a/an] _.”

• *[excuse](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/excuse#Noun)*, “An explanation designed to avoid or alleviate guilt or negative judgment”
• *[self-deprecation](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/self-deprecation)*, “The [disparagement](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/disparagement#Noun) of one's own abilities”
• *[disclaimer](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/disclaimer#Noun)*, “A public disavowal, as of pretensions, claims, opinions, and the like”
• *[alibi](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/alibi#Noun)*, “An excuse, especially one used to avoid responsibility or blame”
• *[apology](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/apology#Noun)*, “An expression of remorse or regret for having said or done something...”

(Link sources: wiktionary)

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but...
"Don't start an answer with (a) **derogation**"

Dictionary.com

- **Derogate**: to detract, as from authority, estimation, etc.

Answer (score 0):

'Don't **prevaricate** / **equivocate**'.

[Google Dictionary]:

> equivocate verb
>
> use ambiguous language so as to conceal the truth or avoid committing
>   oneself.
>
> "the government have equivocated too often in the past"
>
> synonyms: prevaricate, be evasive, be non-committal, be vague, be
>   ambiguous, evade/dodge the issue, beat about the bush, hedge, hedge
>   one's bets, fudge the issue;