# Proper word for caveats in speech?

Tags: vocabulary

Similar to this [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/193638/word-for-beginning-a-statement-with-a-disclaimer-caveat-hedge-when-you-are-w), but slightly different. I am looking for a word or phrase to describe the act of adding in disclaimers or qualifications in sentences to not suggest a certain thing, **especially if it is offensive**. Take in mind that these phrases are often used in situations where one is scared of offending others, so it's likely there are ways of describing it with negative connotations.

Here are some examples:

> "I admire Hitler's military tactics, **not that I think he wasn't a bad person.**"

Notice for this one that the second half of the sentence doesn't change the implication of the first half, but not adding something to that effect at the end might have people come to other conclusions about the writer.

> "**Although I think women can do just as good as men in mathematics,** there are few great female mathematicians."

Once again the first half is not really needed, it is put in to not offend people.

> "If p, then q. **Not that it should be that way and not that q implies p.**"

Again, the second sentence is not really adding more information about the subject, its purpose is to protect the writer or to stop the reader from forming conclusions that have no basis.

This question is different from [this one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/138243/what-is-it-called-when-someone-says-something-like-im-not-a-racist-but) because, in that one the statement that follows the caveat usually contradicts the caveat.

Comment: I dispute that this is a duplicate question. Although some of the answers may apply, my question is different for reasons that I have stated at the end of my question. I feel my question is more specific, as in all my examples the caveat added was useless information, its purpose was to be "politically correct." I do not have enough reputation to make a meta question and the mechanics of disputing a duplicate vote are described vaguely.

Comment: It's not even close to being a duplicate.  Funnily enough, **"it's the opposite"**.  Voting, etc, on these sites is generally Insane, so don't worry about it.

Comment: You'd possibly describe that as "adding a disclaimer..."  the all-time classic example in AmE is a catchphrase from the Seinfeld show ... "The Outing" ... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oj3VphK9AMk  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9OH1yEnENG0

Comment: You've asked about what a disclaimer statement might be called. It makes no difference whether such a statement precedes "but" or follows "although".

Comment: @AndrewLeach Though some of the answers would apply, my question is different. Additionally many of the comments and answers would not make sense for my question. I think this question is at the very least a borderline duplicate. It seems harsh for it to be instantly closed as duplicate, are duplicate questions not decided by duplicate votes?

Comment: @0x41414141 Yes. It only takes one moderator vote (and only one vote of users with a gold "vocabulary" badge in this case). And "some of the answers would apply" means that it **is** a duplicate.